# help in setting up wine gecko

Tags: 16.04, wine

I need wine gecko support on my laptop so I downloaded a file "wine_gecko-2.47-x86.msi" from https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko it's the right version for my wine but I don't know where to put it.
Right now it's sitting in my downloads folder and wine still says that I don't have wine gecko can you help fuiger out where to paste the file?
Thank you for reading.